# Trying to execute stored procedure from UFT

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, vbscript, plsqldeveloper

I have read only access on my projects oracle database. When I execute manually a stored procedure in PLSQL developer it will give xml file output to be used in SOAP UI.

While I am trying to automate the same in UFT I am getting steps in single quotes in query as comments. How to execute the procedure successfully and get the output?

my procedure

[image]

my planned UFT code

```
Set cm = CreateObject(”ADODB.Command”) 

cm.ActiveConnection =  str

' Set the command type to Stored Procedures'

cm.CommandType = 4 

' Stored Procedures' 

cm.CommandText = strProc 

' Define Parameters for the stored procedure'

cm.Execute()
```

Comment: Infact I have to execute atleast 300 lines of PL|SQL statements

Comment: `UFT` as an editor is using `vbscript`.  The `'` char means "what follows is a comment".  You need to build the full string up inside double quotes, appending each line as required.